# vba to create pivot table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, pivot-table

Dears
I'm working on a piviot table and by the way I'm newibe to PT, I tried to record the macro and tried to edit it but it failed so i need your help please.

The needed result is as below snapshot to be in another sheet of the same workbook which contains the source data

[image]

The source data is as below snapshot from another sheet in the same workbook and by the way it is only a part of the whole data which led to the result data as attached above.
[image]

```
Sub Generate_Ter()

'Declare Variables
Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

Set PSheet = Worksheets("New")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("Data")
enter code here
Dim rg2 As Range
With DSheet
Set rg2 = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
rg2.Offset(0, 6).Value = 1
rg2.Resize(rg2.Rows.Count, 7).Name = "PRange"

'Define Pivot Cache
    
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "PRange", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:=PSheet.Range("P1"), TableName:="ptTmp2", DefaultVersion _
        :=xlPivotTableVersion14
        
        With DSheet.PivotTables("ptTmp2").PivotFields("SKU Name")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
        .Subtotals = Array _
        (False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    End With
    
    With DSheet.PivotTables("ptTmp2").PivotFields("SKU Code")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 3
        .Subtotals = Array _
        (False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    End With
    
    
With DSheet.PivotTables("ptTmp2")
    .AddDataField DSheet.PivotTables("ptTmp2"). _
        PivotFields("1"), "BSS Count", xlCount
    .RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
    .RepeatAllLabels xlRepeatLabels
    .ColumnGrand = False
    .ShowTableStyleRowHeaders = False
    .TableRange1.Copy
    End With
    
    PSheet.Range("A9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    PSheet.Range("A9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error message and on what line of code?

Comment: run-time error'1004' the pivottable field name is not valid, to create a pivottable report, u must use data that is organzued as list with labeled columns. if you are changing the name of the pivot table field , you must type a new name for the field .. (error on the line contains: ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData  "PRange", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:=PSheet.Range("P1"), TableName:="ptTmp2", DefaultVersion _
        :=xlPivotTableVersion14)

Comment: `"PRange"` doesn't look like a valid argument for `SourceData`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved after editing code as below,
Mistakes were in defining source data and selecting blanks columns

so

```
rg2.Offset(0, 6).Value = 1
rg2.Resize(rg2.Rows.Count, 7).Name = "PRange"
```

changed to

```
rg2.Offset(0, 4).Value = 1
rg2.Resize(rg2.Rows.Count, 5).Name = "Sdata"

'Define Pivot Cache

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Sdata", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:=DSheet.Range("P1"), TableName:="ptTmp2", DefaultVersion _
        :=xlPivotTableVersion14
```

and below code

```
    With DSheet.PivotTables("ptTmp2").PivotFields("SKU Name")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 2
    .Subtotals = Array _
    (False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
End With

With DSheet.PivotTables("ptTmp2").PivotFields("SKU Code")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 3
    .Subtotals = Array _
    (False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
End With
```

changed to

```
With DSheet.PivotTables("ptTmp2").PivotFields("SKU Name")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
        .Subtotals = Array _
        (False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    End With
    
    With DSheet.PivotTables("ptTmp2").PivotFields("SKU Code")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
        .Subtotals = Array _
        (False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    End With
```